# Write a Regex that accepts string of alphanumeric characters except certain words

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a regex that accepts url with pathname of the form

/exmaple/XXXXX

Here,XXXXX can be a string of alphanumeric keywords but it should not be "create" or "add".

I have created the regex for accepting alphanumeric but I am unable to find a way to add exceptions of "create" or "add".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negative lookahead is your friend, `foo(?!pattern)` means `foo` will not match if `pattern` matches immediately after `foo`. Like other lookarounds, negative lookaheads are not capture groups.

```
/\/example\/(?!create|add)[A-Za-z0-9]+/
```